# Cannot set quote stye in JOOQ (RenderNameStyle.QUOTED)

Tags: java, jooq

I'd like to get JOOQ to render column names with quotes. This is what I tried, reading the docs and StackOverflow:

```
    DSLContext sql = DSL.using( SQLDialect.SQL99, 
            new Settings()
                .withRenderNameStyle(RenderNameStyle.QUOTED)
                .withRenderFormatted(true)
                .withRenderKeywordStyle(RenderKeywordStyle.UPPER)
        );

    System.out.println( "Quoted: " + (sql.settings().getRenderNameStyle()==RenderNameStyle.QUOTED) );

    Table<Record> table = table("MyTable");
    Field<Long> lid = field("id",Long.class);

    String sqlStr = sql.renderInlined(
            sql.select( lid, field("type"), field("request.id"), field("UPPERCASE"), field("lowercase") )
            .from(table)
            .limit(1000) 
        );

    System.out.println(sqlStr);
```

The generated statement is:

```
SELECT 
   id, 
   type, 
   request.id, 
   UPPERCASE, 
   lowercase
FROM MyTable
LIMIT 1000
```

It outputs `Quoted: true`, so the flag seems to be set.
While `renderFormatted` and `renderKeywordStyle` seem to be respected, `renderNameStyle`` appears to be ignored.

I'm experimenting with an unsupported database, therefore the SQL99.
Side question: Why is SQL99 deprecated in JOOQ?

Comment: *"I'm experimenting with an unsupported database"* - what database is that? Maybe we can help...

Comment: The DB is SAP HANA - any help appreciated! I had hoped that there would be a "default SQL" profile that simply tries to stick to the standard, as a fallback for unsupported DBs, but I have not seen one.

Comment: Interesting. We (Data Geekery) have actually been talking to SAP about such an integration and it's going to be a high priority for jOOQ 3.6... Adding support on your side is feasible but probably very tedious. jOOQ has grown quite big, and our `SELECT` statement support is getting more and more complex.

Comment: As a matter of fact, [we will officially support HANA with jOOQ 3.6](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3765)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`DSL.field(String)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field-java.lang.String-) methods are used to embed "plain SQL" into jOOQ. jOOQ doesn't parse your SQL strings, and thus doesn't know which parts you considered to be "names", such as  `type`, or `request` and `id`.

If you don't want to use the code generator, you should use [`DSL.field(Name)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field-org.jooq.Name-) to create fields whose names is affected by the `RenderNameStyle` setting. `Name` can be created using [`DSL.name(String...)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#name-java.lang.String...-)

> I'm experimenting with an unsupported database, therefore the SQL99. Side question: Why is SQL99 deprecated in JOOQ?

Because the name is misleading. jOOQ isn't really generating SQL99 as there are no integration tests verifying that the output is really correct or meaningful according to the standard. In a future version of jOOQ, `SQL99` will be replaced by a `DEFAULT` dialect, which probably won't work on any database.

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it by using fieldByName(). However fieldByName() is now marked as deprecated. What should we use for this usecase?

Comment: @Pierre: Thanks for the hint. I've updated my answer